# Alteryx Designer - How to retrieve only first and last name from field excluding middle initials?

Tags: sql, designer, alteryx

I need help in writing SQL code in Alteryx Designer.

My table `employees` contains a column `Name` with values shown below. However, I need the expected output as shown below.

Please help.

**Name:**

1. Smith, Mary K
2. Koch, J B
3. Batoon Rene, Anne S
4. Vaughan-tre Doctor, Maria S

Excepted output:

1. Smith, Mary
2. Koch, J
3. Batoon Rene, Anne
4. Vaughan-tre, Maria

The middle initials and “Doctor” word is removed.

Comment: Need help in writing the sql code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need to use SQL if you have the data in Alteryx?

So, you need to remove the right hand 2 characters and the word 'Doctor' from each record?

You could use the Formula tool, though I suspect there are numerous other ways:

```
replace (TrimRight([Name],' '+right([Name],1)),'Doctor','')
```